# How can I provide a textbox that filters results in real time using ASP.NET MVC and jQuery (NOT autocomplete)?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I'm looking to something similar to how the [Stackoverflow Users page](https://stackoverflow.com/users) allows you to type in a username and it filter the users below in real time.

[image]

I'm using ASP.NET MVC and jQuery.  Can someone point me to a simplified example that uses this technology stack to do the same thing?

Comment: Do you have a lot of items to filter? Can the filtering be on the client side? I suspect Stackoverflow does the filtering on the server.

Comment: Did you look at the source?  Looks like just a Web Service that returns the result, and that result is thrown in a div.

Answer (score 4):

You basically need an ajax call made each time the value of the textbox changes.

Totally untested, but something along the lines of:

```
$("#inputName").change(function () {
    // maybe check the value is more than n chars or whatever
    $.ajax({
        url: <%= Url.Action("Lookup", "Users") %> + '/' + this.val(), // path to ajax request
        dataType: "html", // probably
        success: updateContainerWithResults
    });
});

function updateContainerWithResults(data) {
    $("#resultsContainerElement").html(data);
}
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Events/change

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax

Comment: FYI `change` only fires on blur of the textbox, not on every keystroke.

Comment: So what event should be used then for each keystroke?

Comment: keyup. However, you might want to take a look at some of the autocomplete jquery functions. You'd have to modify them to suit your needs, but they offer some improvement. Ie, if someone is typing john, and they type 'j', do you really want to search for all users with the letter j? If they type j-o-h-n really quickly, do you really want to send 4 separate requests to the server?

Comment: @redsquare: `<input type="text" />` fires change on blur or submit of the parent form (if any). See http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/change.html . What browsers do you see this behavior *not* happen? Curious...